# How to make pdist ignore a value (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, euclidean-distance

I am using `pdist` to calculate euclidian distances between three dimensional points (in Matlab). However i have some coordinates that i cannot remove from the matrix, but that i want `pdist` to ignore.

I have tried overwriting the values i want to ignore with `NaN`'s, but `pdist` still uses them in the calculation. Is there a way to make pdist ignore a value in it's process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know `pdist`, but it looks like you need to remove certain rows for it to work the way you want.  If you were to find the indices of the rows you don't want, you could do the following:

```
d = [1,2,3;2,3,4;3,4,5]
d =
    1   2   3
    2   3   4
    4   5   6
i = [1 3]
d(i,:)
    1   2   3
    4   5   6
id = pdist(d(i,:)) % assume id=2
real_index = i(id) % now the real index is i(2)=3
```

Now you would have the index of the row in `real_index`. (pdist doesn't seem to exist in my matlab so I can't get the real output, but the idea is there!)

Comment: I know, but removing the rows is not what i want (that will change the indexes, which is what i need eventually). I need a way to make `pdist` ignore values, without having to remove the actual data.

Comment: It won't change the variable itself - it just passes an anonymous variable without the rows to pdist (ie pdist(d(i,:)) ). d will remain the same.

Comment: Yeah, but it will change the input for `pdist` (and thus the output). Say i have a matrix `d` for which the second row has the smallest distance. After removing the first row, `pdist` will return `1` as the index for the row with the smallest distance (which is wrong for `d`).

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't realize the output of pdist was dependent on that.  What about using the output of pdist as the index to i to get back the original row? Would that work? I modified the answer to reflect this.

Comment: That's a good idea, sort of like using `find` you mean? I'll try it!

Comment: Yeah, it's like `find`, but direct indexing is generally faster, I believe.  Actually, if you use `find` in the code editor, it will often suggest switching to direct indexing for speed.